# Display specific columns from Input dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to display predictions and associated input rows. I have 5 column inputs, but in the case of output, I want to display just the first two columns from input and associated predictions. I do not want to see col3 col4 and col5 in the output display. Could someone help me? Thank you.

```
like 
col1 col2 predictions
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',delimiter=',')
df.head() 
X = df[['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']].values   

filename = 'pickle_m1.pkl'
classifier_model_reloaded = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

predictions=classifier_model_reloaded.predict(X) 

for i in range(len(predictions)):
    print(X[i], predictions[i])
```

```
[ 3.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  3.70000000e+01
  0.00000000e+00  3.10000000e+01  6.00000000e+00  1.85000000e+01
  1.76776695e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  1.23000000e+07  6.66666667e+05  3.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
  3.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  6.66666667e+05
  0.00000000e+00  6.00000000e+00  3.10000000e+01  2.26666667e+01
  1.44337567e+01  2.08333333e+02  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  3.40000000e+01
  1.85000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  2.00000000e+00  3.70000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  6.00000000e+01 -1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+01
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00] 0
[ 3.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  3.70000000e+01
  0.00000000e+00  3.10000000e+01  6.00000000e+00  1.85000000e+01
  1.76776695e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  1.23000000e+07  6.66666667e+05  3.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
  3.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  6.66666667e+05
  0.00000000e+00  6.00000000e+00  3.10000000e+01  2.26666667e+01
  1.44337567e+01  2.08333333e+02  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  3.40000000e+01
  1.85000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  2.00000000e+00  3.70000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  6.20000000e+01 -1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+01
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00] 0


only predictions [i]

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

This displays all input columns.

Comment: HI, what are the type (and shape?) of `predictions`?

Comment: @Laurent predictions just 0 and 1

Comment: Ok, but what is `predictions` as a container? A list? A list of list? A list of dataframes? Coudl you add an example of what `predictions[i]` outputs?

Comment: predictions are 0 and 1 as you can see above, it is displayed in such weird form, in actual I have 80 input columns so I need to show just 4 with associated predictions @Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
# Previous code unchanged
...
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    print(df.loc[i, ["col1", "col2"]].values, predictions[i])
```